# Simple way to do SURBL lookup from Java?

Tags: java, dns, spam

I am reading about [SURBLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURBL) (known spam hosts), for purpose of classifying spam, as a batch process. Main access method seems to be via DNS lookups. I was wondering what's the usual way to do such lookups from Java code. Since this is a batch process with no strict performance requirements, I think most important feature would just be simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
InetAddress.getByName("test.multi.surbl.org").getHostAddress();
```

If the hostname can not be resolved, it's not listed. If it can be resolved, the last octet of the ip address [indicates where it's listed](http://www.surbl.org/lists.html#multi).

There's also [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) if you need more advanced features. For example, perhaps you would like to check the TXT record too.